# Can I bring testosterone gel with me to Germany?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, health, drugs, lgbt

I'm a trans person, and I want to bring testosterone gel I bought abroad (legally but without a prescription) into Germany.

[Customs says the following](https://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/Restrictions/Medicinal-products-and-narcotics/medicinal-products-and-narcotics_node.html):

> substances that are particularly harmful and frequently used for doping and are listed in the Annex to Section 6a of the Medicinal Products Act (for example: testosteron, nandrolon, clenbuterol), of which the possession for the purpose of doping in sports in "not small quantities" is already prohibited. What quantity of these substances shall be seen as "not small" follows from the Doping Substances (Quantities) Regulation (Dopingmittel-Mengen-Verordnung).

Dopingmittel-Mengen-Verordnung states that transdermal testosterone under 1500mg is considered small quantities, and I have under 1500mg.

Would I be allowed to bring this into Germany without issues?

Comment: Do you have any reason to doubt the sources you have provided?

Comment: @mdewey the wording is unclear on the page. Different people I've asked to parse it parsed it as different things.

Comment: The column in the Dopingmittel-Mengen-Verordnung is headed _nicht geringe Menge_ which suggests to me that it means _not small_. I think you need to email the German Health Ministry to get a definitive answer.

Comment: @mdewey do you have recommendations who to contact exactly?

Comment: No, sorry. One other thought though (I am not medically qualified) what is the half-life of testosterone in the body? If you stopped for the duration of your trip to Germany would that have deleterious effects? Perhaps your physician can advise.

Comment: @mdewey I live in germany.

Comment: I do find the guidance is a little oddly-written (both in English and in German), and leaves me not entirely certain whether the "not small amount" allowance is relevant to entering Germany or only to possession within Germany. @user139075 as you linked only to the English version of the customs website, I'm going to assume you'd prefer to contact them in English - [this page](https://www.zoll.de/EN/Contact/Enquiries/General-enquiries/general-enquiries_node.html) seems to have the appropriate details.

Comment: The text you quoted talks about 'not small quantities'. There is a specific amount that defines a not small quantity (1500 mg) and you are below that. Hence the paragraph you quoted **does not apply** to you. I don't know whether other restrictions do apply, hence no answer and just a comment.

Answer (score 4):

I spoke to someone from the German customs centre. You are permitted to bring up to 3 months worth of testosterone-containing medication (in my case I was asking about gels) into the country, provided you can prove you are using it for a legitimate medical purpose (e.g. with a prescription or doctors note) and not doping for sports etc.